How do you get a VStack to start of the Top of the screen in swift?
How do I get a VStact to appear at the top of the screen? I have tried all sorts (see below) but whatever I try my menu stubbornly appears in the middle of the screen.
struct ContentView: View {
    

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top)
        {
            VStack(alignment: .center)
            {
                Menu{
                    Button("Initial Setup", action: buildMeals)
                    Button("", action: mySpacer)
                    Button("Mi Babe", action: hibabe)
                } label: {
                    Label("Options", systemImage: "menubar.arrow.down.rectangle")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

}


Add a Spacer() under Menu
